# Querying comma separated data using Regex

Tags: regex, field

I have following data in  three rows:

abc=5,def=1245,ghi=888,jkl=235,mno=854

abc=6,def=1254369,ghi=52158789,jkl=985214526,mno=851

abc=2,def=8952436,ghi=85479,jkl=852146,mno=2

Using regex I need to find something like this

if abc= 6 then get the value of ghi  (this should be 52158789)

similarly if
abc= 6 then get the value of jkl  (this should be 985214526)

similarly if
abc= 2 then get the value of jkl  (this should be 852146)
etc

Comment: Do you use a programming language or just a text editor?

Comment: Just a text editor.

Comment: Then what text editor do you use? What RegEx type does it provide?

Comment: i was trying them out in https://regex101.com/

Comment: I stumbled upon one abc=1,.*,ghi=(([0-9]*))   which works but following does not work:     abc=1,.*,def=(([0-9]*))     Apparently this regex cannot get value of the 2nd field.